# Is there a mathematical/encryption algorithm/model that allows you to shorten/compress any number?

Tags: language-agnostic, compression

Suppose you have a large number, 99999999999. Is there any methodology available to compress that to a much shorter number, say "234.56" assuming you can store reference information in the background (i.e information on what methods to use to "decompress", get from 234.56 back to 999999999)

Comment: Of course there is, this is the entire basis of [lossless data compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression#Lossless) (RLE, Lempel-Ziv, or any of several others). You'll have to narrow the scope of the question for meaningful answers other than "yes, pick a compression algorithm" to be possible.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity

Comment: You haven't said how you are storing the number currently.  If it is in an ascii decimal form as written, then the first thing to do is convert it to binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, and taking your question literally, **no**. Some numbers will always get bigger, or stay the same size.

It's easy to show this : assume the answer to your question was "yes". You get a shorter number from your bigger number. Reapply until you end up with a 0 digit number. See the problem?

But that aside, you can use any lossless compression algorithm. Stick them all in a binary file and zip the whole thing up if required. You'll need a lot of numbers to compress at once to beat the overhead though.. and if these are random numbers you're out of luck - [no algorithm can compress randomness](http://marknelson.us/2006/06/20/million-digit-challenge/).

Of course depending on your sample space you may be able to do much better. If you know they're likely to consist of 1 digit repeated for instance, you could simply store the digit, and the run length, with an escape sequence for numbers that don't fit that pattern. If you know there are 256 different common numbers, store those with your program and then just a byte index into that array, plus an escape sequence for numbers not in the array. Etc.

But again, the answer to your problem in general is **no**.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "store reference information in the background". In the extreme case, the "reference information" would be the number itself and the "compressed" number would just be the index to the "reference information". Basically you'd have a URL shortener for numbers.